Can I get the taps and the initial state of an lfsr, just knowing a part of the final keystream?
So, imagine you have an lsr sequence like this:  1101 0111 1000 1001
That has been obtained from the initial sequence: 1011 using as taps position 1 and position 0, like this:
1011->1
0101->1
1010->0
1101->1
1110->0
1111->1
0111->1
0011->1
0001->1
1000->0
0100->0
0010->0
1001->1
1100->0
0110->0
1011->1

The question is if you can obtained the whole sequence with just this part of the output:
1101 0111

According to this article I've read, it's possible, but I can't make it with this example
https://medium.com/@massin.laaouaj/lfsr-criptograf%C3%ADa-7a6116cf011c
Thank you all for the help

Welcome to crypto-SE. This falls into the "Basic homework" category of our charter, so you must show efforts towards resolution or the question will get closed. Knowing $2n$ consecutive output bits of a binary LFSR with $n$ latches, the Berlekamp–Massey algorithm finds the taps and the state before the known part of the output sequence, and from that whatever part of the output sequence.

Sorry, didn't know those restrictions of "basic homework", anyways in the article it didn't mention the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm, but I suppose it's what he does.
Thank you, for the answer. I just misread the article I guess
